# How to test StreamBuilder that has a delay in the stream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a stream that has a delay in it. StreamBuilder never gets the value "foo" from the stream in the test. If the delay is removed then the test works as expected. How can I tell the test to wait for this delay?

```
testWidgets('stream builder', (tester) async {
  final textKey = Key('textKey');
  final stream = Observable.just('foo').delay(Duration(milliseconds: 1));

  var app = MaterialApp(
    home: StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
            snapshot.data ?? 'no data',
            key: textKey,
          ),
    ),
  );

  await tester.pumpWidget(app);
  await tester.pump(Duration.zero);

  Text text = tester.widget(find.byKey(textKey));
  expect(text.data, equals('foo'));
});
```

This fails with the error

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞══════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: 'foo'
  Actual: 'no data'
   Which: is different.
          Expected: foo
            Actual: no data
                    ^
           Differ at offset 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution. The trick is to wrap it in `tester.runAsync()` and I also had to add `tester.idle()`.

```
testWidgets('stream builder', (tester) async {
  final textKey = Key('textKey');

  await tester.runAsync(() async { // IMPORTANT
    final stream = Observable.just('foo').delay(Duration(milliseconds: 1));

    var app = MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
              snapshot.data ?? 'no data',
              key: textKey,
            ),
      ),
    );

    await tester.pumpWidget(app);
    await tester.idle(); // IMPORTANT
    await tester.pump(Duration.zero); // IMPORTANT
  });

  Text text = tester.widget(find.byKey(textKey));
  expect(text.data, equals('foo'));
});
```

Comment: What do tester methods `idle()` and `pump(zero)` actually add to the equation?

They helped me to resolve similar issue with BLoC state handling during test run, but would like to understand why :)